# How can i measure running time comparison of C code?

Tags: c++, c, time-complexity

Example code 1:

```
const int N=100000;

for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
    arr1[j] += a1[j];
    arr2[j] += a2[j];
}
```

Example code 2:

```
for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
    arr1[j] += a1[j];
}
for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
    arr2[j] += a2[j];
}
```

I need to calculate the running time of these block of code. Is there any tool(benchmark) to calculate it?

Comment: you can use the ctime or with c++11 the chronos library would you need an example?

Comment: you can use the linux time command, or you can use a profiling tool such as OProfile

Comment: You'll probably need to set N to more than 100,000 to get anything significant.

Comment: @pyCthon, An example code would be better to understand.

Comment: Get a profiler for your platform and use it.

Comment: I bet 10 bucks on number two as the fastest one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

const int N=100000;

void time_first() {
  struct timeval start, mid, end;
  long mtime, seconds, useconds;    

  gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
  for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
    arr1[j] += a1[j];
    arr2[j] += a2[j];
  }  
  gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

  seconds  = end.tv_sec  - start.tv_sec;
  useconds = end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec;

  mtime = ((seconds) * 1000 + useconds/1000.0) + 0.5;

  printf("First elapsed time: %ld milliseconds\n", mtime);
}

void time_second() {
  struct timeval start, mid, end;
  long mtime, seconds, useconds;    

  gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
  for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
    arr1[j] += a1[j];
  }
  for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
    arr2[j] += a2[j];
  }
  gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

  seconds  = end.tv_sec  - start.tv_sec;
  useconds = end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec;

  mtime = ((seconds) * 1000 + useconds/1000.0) + 0.5;

  printf("Second elapsed time: %ld milliseconds\n", mtime);
}

int main() {
  initialize arr1, a1 and a2

  time_first();
  time_second();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're running under a system that includes it you can just execute it under `time`:

```
$ time ./benchmark1
```

and

```
$ time ./benchmark2
```

Comment: Output doesn't matter.  Think of it as a stopwatch that starts when you start the program and stops when it returns.  Yes, benchmark1 and 2 are the programs compiled from above.