# Which of these C multiplication algorithms is easier CPU and has lower overhead?

Tags: c, performance, multiplication

I want to know which of these functions is easier for CPU to calculate/run. I was told that direct multiplication (e.g. 4x3) is more difficult for CPU to calculate than a series of summation (e.g. 4+4+4). Well the first one has direct multiplication, but the second one has a for loop.

## Algorithm 1

The first one is like `x*y`:

```
int multi_1(int x, int y)
{
    return x * y;
}
```

## Algorithm 2

The second one is like `x+x+x+...+x` (as much as y):

```
int multi_2(int num1, int num2)
{
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0; i<num2; i++)
    {
        sum += num1;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Please don't respond with "Don't try to do micro-optimization" or something similar. How can I evaluate which of these codes run better/faster? Does C language automatically convert direct multiplication to summation?

Comment: You can check it yourself if you take a look at the generated assembly.

Comment: It's a rather wild idea to implement multiplication using loop-add. The truth is, if your compiler provides `operator *`, it makes very sure it's the fastest possible standard-compliant implementation within the capability of the processor.

Comment: I'm sure multi_1 is faster. But this is a classical case for profiling or a debugging of the generated assembler code

Answer (score 4):

You can generally expect the multiplication operator `*` to be implemented as efficiently as possible. Beating it with a custom multiplication algorithm is highly unlikely. If for any reason `multi_2` is faster than `multi_1` for all but some edge cases, consider writing a bug report against your compiler vendor.

On modern (i.e. made in this century) machines, multiplications by arbitrary integers are extremely fast and takes four cycles at most, which is faster than initializing the loop in `multi_2`.

Comment: `arbitrary integer` is quite an ambitious statement. 128=64x64 takes at least 7 cycles on Cortex-A57(4 for `SMULH` and 3 for x-form `MUL/MADD`), and I assume it takes even longer on A53 and A35, and suspect if any shorter on A72. So, you just killed the entire ARMv8 family including poor 10-day-old A35....

Comment: Historically, early models of a new word width generation usually only implement single-cycle multiplier for half-word multiplicand/multiplier and full-word product. Multiplication scales O(mn) with word length, so a full word multiplication with double word product takes at least 4 cycles plus additional cycles to sum 4 partial product into 1 final product. Simply put, 64 bit chips are still too young to do fast 128=64x64.

Answer (score 2):

The more "high level" your code is, the more optimization paths your compiler will be able to use. So, I'd say that code #1 will have the most chances to produce a fast and optimized code.

In fact, for a simple CPU architecture that doesn't support direct multiplication operations, but does support addition and shifts, the second algorithm won't be used at all. The usual procedure is something similar to the following code:

```
unsigned int mult_3 (unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
{
  unsigned int res = 0;
  while (x)
  {
    res += (x&1)? y : 0;
    x>>=1;
    y<<=1;
  }
  return res;
}
```

Comment: I love O(log(N)) algorithms.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens how about O(log log n)? Like a Wallace tree or Dadda tree. Doesn't look great in software though.

Answer (score 1):

Typical modern CPUs can do multiplication in hardware, often at the same speed as addition. So clearly #1 is better.

Even if multiplication is not available and you are stuck with addition there are algorithms much faster than #2.

Answer (score 1):

You were misinformed. Multiplication is not "more difficult" than repeated addition. Multipliers are built-into in the ALU (Arithmetic & Logical Unit) of modern CPU, and they work in constant time. On the opposite, repeated additions take time proportional to the value of one of the operands, which could be as large a one billion !

Actually, multiplies rarely performed by straight additions; when you have to implement them in software, you do it by repeated shifts, using a method similar to [duplation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_multiplication), known of the Ancient Aegyptiens.

Comment: Some processors (even modern ones) cannot do multiplication in hardware, multiplication circuits are quite large which is a good reason not to have them. Others implement hardware multiplication as a duplication loop in 8 or 16 clocks and possibly not in constant time

Comment: While it's technically O(1), it's more O(log min(*n, m*)) but n and m are bounded above by the word length. Anyway, it's important not to assume that these are constant time operations in a cryptographic sense because they aren't and may make cryptographic algorithms vulnerable to side-channel attacks.

Comment: I do. Anybody who writes cryptography code does. Anybody who writes code with tight timing does. You don't, but that's not the point.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the architecture you run it on, as well as the compiler and the values for x and y.

If x and y are small, the second version might be faster. However, when x and y are very large numbers, the second version will certainly be much slower.

The only way to really find out is to measure the running time of your code, for example like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9085330/369009

Comment: On modern systems, a multiplication takes 4 cycles at most. Thus the overhead of looping in the second algorithm already kills the performance for the case of `num2` being zero.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dealing with `int` values, the multiplication operator (`*`) will be far more efficient. C will compile into the CPU-specific assembly language, which will have a multiplication instruction (e.g., x86's `mul`/`imul`). Virtually all modern CPUs can multiply integers within a few clock cycles. It doesn't get much faster than that. Years ago (and on some relatively uncommon embedded CPUs) it used to be the case that multiplication took more clock cycles than addition, but even then, the additional `jump` instructions to loop would result in more cycles being consumed, even if only looping once or twice.

Answer (score 0):

The C language does not require that multiplications by integers be converted into series of additions.  It permits implementations to do that, I suppose, but I would be surprised to find an implementation that did so, at least in the general context you present.

Note also that in your case #2 you have replaced one multiplication operation with not just `num2` addition operations, but with at least `2 * num2` additions, `num2` comparisons, and `2 * num2` storage operations.  The storage operations probably end up being approximately free, as the values likely end up living in CPU registers, but they don't *have* to do.

Overall, I would expect alternative #1 to be much faster, but it is always best to answer performance questions by *testing*.  You will see the largest difference for large values of `num2`.  For instance, try with `num1` == 1 and `num2` == `INT_MAX`.